# How to Select Submenu with Selenium MoveToElement?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The web app I'm testing has a two-level left-side panel menu. I'm trying to select a sub-menu item. I had the code working:

```
CHIA_LIB_Selenium_Wait.UntilElementDisplayed(DriverObj, By.LinkText(m_MenuItems(0)))

LinkObj = DriverObj.FindElement(By.LinkText(m_MenuItems(0)))

DriverObj.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 60)

BuilderObj.MoveToElement(LinkObj).Build.Perform()

If m_MenuItems.Count = 2 Then
    If m_MenuItems(1) IsNot Nothing Then
        CHIA_LIB_Selenium_Wait.UntilElementDisplayed(DriverObj, By.LinkText(m_MenuItems(1)))
        LinkObj = DriverObj.FindElement(By.LinkText(m_MenuItems(1)))
        BuilderObj.MoveToElement(LinkObj, 5, 5).Click().Build.Perform()
    End If
End If
```

Now this code is finding and selecting another sub-menu item that is in the same position as the sub-menu item I want to select.

It's too hard to describe in words what's happening. Let's try a diagram. I Suppose I want to select Sub1C. I find and move over Main1. The browser displays the Sub1A, Sub1B, and Sub1C menu items:

```
Main1 - Sub1A
Main2   Sub1B
Main3   Sub1C
```

The code finds and tries to click on Sub1C.

But what actually happens is the code moves the mouse to Main3 and selects and clicks on Sub3A menu item.

```
Main1
Main2
Main3 - Sub3A
```

You see that Sub3A is positioned in the same location as the Sub1A menu item.

My environment:
    Windows 7 64-bit
    InternetExplorerDriver 3.8.0
    Edge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Select Submenu with Selenium MoveToElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524343/how-to-select-submenu-with-selenium-movetoelement)

Comment: Can you please share the url where u are trying this ?

Comment: @Andersson. SO site was having server problems at the time of my submission. I might have clicked on submit button twice.

Comment: @Ankur - The web application is an internal web app for a U.S. state agency. I can't provide access to that app. However, I'll try to replicate the menu and see if I can post on a public site.

Comment: You should delete either of the two identical posts @CoolBreeze.

Comment: I deleted 2nd post. Just wondering if I need to set an IE option when opening InternetExplorerDriver to fix this problem.

Comment: I found a workaround. I vertically spaced the main menu items by 120px. This caused the submenus items to not overlap. The test code now successfully selects the correct submenu item and my tests are proceeding. However, that workaround is a kluge and temporary workaround. I'm hoping someone has a real workaround.